# How to do bootstrap validation with using other css frameworks

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, formvalidation-plugin, formvalidation.io

friends am started to doing bootstrap validation by taking reference from http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-success-error-colors/

At the end of the page there is a download option. When I click download they told use something like foundation, pure, semantic and ui kit.

I want to do exactly what they have done - can anyone explain how to do that?

Here is my fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/0s9xw5rx/2/

**Css:**

```
.field-error .control-label,
.field-error .help-block,
.field-error .form-control-feedback {
    color: #ff0039;
}

.field-success .control-label,
.field-success .help-block,
.field-success .form-control-feedback {
    color: #2780e3;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        row: {
            valid: 'field-success',
            invalid: 'field-error'
        },
        fields: {
            username: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: hi there, no replies from you for a long time. can we help?

Answer (score 1):

your question is too open and unclear. 
Formvalidtion.io is a library to validate forms for framework users. it means if I'm using Bootstrap/Foundation... i can use the framework's Forms design and behavior **with** this library.

please answer the following question so we can help you:

- do you use a framework in your site? if so, which one?
- have you implemented a form?
- have you connected the library to the site as instructed in the docs?